# How to escape ':' in tmux format prefix

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to extract the remote host of a system I'm SSHing into.

tmux's `pane_title` variable looks like:

```
username@host: ~
```

And I tried to set the window status like:

```
:setw -g window-status-format ' #I:#{s/^.*@(.*):.*/\1/i:pane_title}'
```

But with this, the window status looks like `1:`, so maybe tmux is misinterpreting the first colon?

Is there a way to escape a `:` in a prefix?

I tried using a backslash to escape it:

```
:setw -g window-status-format ' #I:#{s/^.*@(.*)\:.*/\1/i:pane_title}'
```

But that did not change the window status.

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: [Literal interpretation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS)

> An ‘l’ specifies that a string should be interpreted literally and not expanded.  For example ‘#{l:#{?pane_in_mode,yes,no}}’ will be replaced by ‘#{?pane_in_mode,yes,no}’.

So your format string would use `#{l::}`:

```
:setw -g window-status-format ' #I:#{s/^.*@(.*)#{l::}.*/\1/i:pane_title}'
```

## Option 2: [ASCII codepoint substitution](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS)

> ‘a’ replaces a numeric argument by its ASCII equivalent, so ‘#{a:98}’ results in ‘b’.

`:` is [ASCII 0x3A/#58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set), so your format string would use `#{a:58}`:

```
:setw -g window-status-format ' #I:#{s/^.*@(.*)#{a:58}.*/\1/i:pane_title}'
```